# Anonymous users unable to access Google web app

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

**Issue:**

Google Apps Script web app is not accessible by anonymous users (users not signed in to any Google account).

Error message:
`403. That's an error.`
`We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page.  That's all we know`

---

**Troubleshooting:**

- I have the web app deployed to execute as "Me" and *Who Has Access* is set to "Anyone"
- In the Google Admin console; Drive and Docs; Sharing Settings: I have sharing outside the organization set to ON and confirmed my user account is not inheriting any conflicting settings
- The Apps Script project is shared as viewable by "Anyone with the link"

The web app opens and functions without issue as long as the user is signed into **any** Google account.  When attempting to access the web app in incognito mode or otherwise not signed into a Google account, a 403 error occurs.  Just to confirm, here is my `appscript.json`:

```js
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

From what I have read on [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and other [stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+web+app+anonymous), there shouldn't be an issue.  What am I missing?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation and if this is related to your current issue, for example, when you deploy your Web Apps as a new version and test it again, what result will you obtain? In that case, the deployment ID is changed and the URL is changed. Please be careful about this. If this was not related to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: That is a good point as I have been caught off-guard by the deployment URL changing before but in this case I am certain the URL I am testing is the most current version and that the web app has been redeployed since the last changes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful.